# How to calculate annualized returns given table of DCF?

Tags: investing, value-investing

I was reading the Dhandho Investor by Mohinish Pabrai, and I came acorss this table:

[image: The DCF table of Papa Patel].

In context to this table the author goes in to say that for and investment of 5000$ the owner makes a 21 bagger. He further adds on to say that the annualized return in well over 50%. Could someone tell me how is the annualized return calculated here? Because each time I tried to calculate it I get approx 36%.

[image: The return on investment as explained by the author.]

Comment: Are you using the initial investment of $5,000 instead of $50,000? This assumes that the other 45k is borrowed, which increases the leverage to 10X,

Comment: Yes I am assuming the initial investment as 5k. Can you please answer the question using this information?

Comment: How is the annualized return 50%

Comment: Total return = 150,000, initial investment = 5,000, for a total return of 3100%. That's an annualized return of 141%, which is "well over" 50%. I can;t reconcile where the "21 bagger" comes from using just that data.

Comment: Can you please tell how you calculated Annualized returns.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_annual_growth_rate - `r = (F/P)^(1/T) - 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122448/discussion-between-spiritmonster-and-d-stanley).